# How to get the current region DateFormat like "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: c#

I'm using the System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker control. This control allows the user to select a date in the calendar, but also to write directly a date.

I'm looking to give users the information on how to write this date.

So I'm basically looking for a way to display the format of a general date (not a specific date)

I know the following:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d")); //  Gives 7/9/2001
```

It looks like the DatePicker uses the "d" format, **so I'm looking for a way to get the following string "dd/mm/yyyy"**

On the French (canada) region, it's "yyyy-mm-dd" for example

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why can't you just format it..? also not that `dd/mm/yyyy` is not the same as `dd/MM/yyyy` I will post a working example of what you need to do you can test it

Comment: No what I was looking for. See the Becuzz answer. (thx for your time though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get a CultureInfo object, it has a DateTimeFormat property on it.  That has a [ShortDatePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which shows the pattern it uses to format dates.

From the linked MSDN article:

```
public class SamplesDTFI  
{
   public static void Main()  
   {
      string[]  cultures = { "en-US", "ja-JP", "fr-FR" };
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1);

      Console.WriteLine(" {0,7} {1,19} {2,10}\n", "CULTURE", "PROPERTY VALUE", "DATE");

      foreach (var culture in cultures) {
         DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture).DateTimeFormat;
         Console.WriteLine(" {0,7} {1,19} {2,10}", culture, 
                           dtfi.ShortDatePattern, 
                           date1.ToString("d", dtfi));
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//        CULTURE      PROPERTY VALUE       DATE
//       
//          en-US            M/d/yyyy   5/1/2011
//          ja-JP          yyyy/MM/dd 2011/05/01
//          fr-FR          dd/MM/yyyy 01/05/2011
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was afraid no-one would get my question but you did! And it's what I was looking for, I didn't know about the DateTimeFormat property and the ShortDatePattern.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `DateTimeFormatInfo` object you get from the `CultureInfo`.  There are some properties on the `DateTimeFormatInfo` that end with "Pattern".  Here is a list I generated:

```
Current culture: en-US

Property                             Format                                Result
--------------------                 -----------------------------         -------------
FullDateTimePattern                : dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt      - Thursday, February 04, 2016 3:51:17 PM
LongDatePattern                    : dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy                 - Thursday, February 04, 2016
LongTimePattern                    : h:mm:ss tt                          - 3:51:17 PM
MonthDayPattern                    : MMMM dd                             - February 04
RFC1123Pattern                     : ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' - Thu, 04 Feb 2016 15:51:17 GMT
ShortDatePattern                   : M/d/yyyy                            - 2/4/2016
ShortTimePattern                   : h:mm tt                             - 3:51 PM
SortableDateTimePattern            : yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss       - 2016-02-04T15:51:17
UniversalSortableDateTimePattern   : yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'      - 2016-02-04 15:51:17Z
YearMonthPattern                   : MMMM, yyyy                          - February, 2016
```

As you can see, your desired result `"dd/mm/yyyy"` isn't there.  To get it, you'll have to hardcode it.

For the curious (the following code isn't meant to answer the question), this is the code I used to generate the above table:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var fmt = culture.DateTimeFormat;
Debug.WriteLine("Current culture: " + culture.Name);
foreach (var prop in fmt.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Pattern")))
{
    var pattern = prop.GetValue(fmt) as string;
    Debug.WriteLine("{0,-35}: {1,-35} - {2}", prop.Name, pattern, DateTime.Now.ToString(pattern));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`